# Apache beam FixedWindow doesn't do anything after GroupByKey transform

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pipeline, apache-beam, dataflow

I built a pipeline which reads from confluent kafka it processes the records and then use side outputs to split them into rejected and approved pcollections, then the approved pcollections gets written to bigquery, but I want to persist the approved records and write them into a file on gcs.

The code is:

```
windowing=(aproved
| 'Create_window'  >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(60))
| 'AddKey' >> beam.Map(lambda record: (none,record))
| 'GBK' >> beam.GroupByKey()
| 'remove_key' >> beam.FlatMap(ret_key)
| 'AddTimeStamp' >> beam.Map(lambda record: beam.window.TimestampValue(record,time.time()))
| 'Write' >> WriteToFiles(path=MY_BUCKET,file_naming=destination_prefix_naming('.ppl'))
)
```

This works when I test it reading from a file and using direct runner, but when I use dataflow and streaming it just doesn't do anything after the GroupByKey transform, it says on the graph that 20 element were added, but the next transform ('remove_key') never gets an element after that

Comment: Is your watermark (from kafka) advancing?

Comment: ohh no it isn't advancing I'm think I know where to look now, I will update with my fix as soon as I can However I made the code work by adding a different trigger than the default because it seems I was opening the window but I never specified when to commit so of course it wasnt doing anyhting after the group by key